# Add two values resulting from a SUM() as a new column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got the following query:

```
SELECT 
    permit_id, 
    SUM(poc_emissions) AS POC_emissions, 
    SUM(non_poc_emissions) AS NON_POC_emissions
FROM 
    ( .... SUBQUERY ...) main
GROUP BY 
    permit_id
```

What I need to do now is to add the values from `POC_emissions` and `NON_POC_emissions` into a new column called let's say `TOTAL`.

I tried:

```
SELECT 
    permit_id, 
    SUM(poc_emissions) AS POC_emissions, 
    SUM(non_poc_emissions) AS NON_POC_emissions, 
    (POC_emissions + NON_POC_emissions) AS Total
FROM 
    ( .... SUBQUERY ...) main
GROUP BY 
    permit_id
```

but it gives me an error.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: If you already *tease* us by saying *it gives me an error*, you should **AT LEAST** tell us ***WHAT*** error that is! After all - we cannot see your screen, nor read your mind - please **TELL US!**

Comment: I think any of the below two answers will work, but it really depends.
In SUM( A + B )   if value A is null then the total for that row becomes NULL.   But in SUM(A) + SUM(B)  the total will include the value of B.

Comment: The answer below works in my case, but you're right. You just need to tweak it a little bit so it can work with null values, you'll need to replace NULL values by 0: SUM(ISNULL(poc_emissions,0) + SUM(ISNULL(non_poc_emissions,0) AS TOTAL

Comment: Sagar is right in pointing out the case where one value will be null, but there will be a lot many such cases when SUM(A+B) will not give the correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Query:

```
SELECT   permit_id, 
         Sum(poc_emissions)                            AS Totle_Poc_emissions, 
         Sum(non_poc_emissions)                        AS Total_Non_poc_emissions, 
         (Sum(poc_emissions) + Sum(non_poc_emissions)) AS total 
FROM     ( .... subquery ...) main 
GROUP BY permit_id
```

Reason:

You can not use new aliases `Totle_Poc_emissions` and `Total_Non_poc_emissions` you gave as a sql query follows an [order of execution](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/683719/Order-of-Execution-of-SQL-Queries), which implies **`FROM` and `GROUP BY` happen before `SELECT`**. So your `GROUP BY` won't know what the new aliases are as `SELECT` will happen afterwards, it will just know the column names.

Comment: I just did the same and it worked, I was about to delete the question. Thanks anyway

Comment: Do you wanna know the technical reason of why that didn't work?

Comment: Read the Edited answer. Hope it helps.